# Why my change doesn't appear in production until I empty the cache of my browser?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I work on a JHipster monolithic application build with maven, front is angular.
All changes I made don't appear unless I empty the cache of my browser (ctrl + f5).
I use firefox and chrome.

I tried to add 'progma: no-cache' (in requests made to the back) with [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-prevent-http-request-caching-with-angular-httpclient-e82abf8b157d), it's worked but that not solve my issue.

I don't know what you need to see so tell me and I will add it to the post.

Thanks you in advance.

**EDIT 1**

thanks Mr. Marziou for your comment sorry for the delay of my awnser,
I just tried what [the article](https://medium.com/@aakashbumiya/auto-reload-for-clients-after-deploy-with-angular-7-production-build-bdc45be9b2bd) suggest, unfortunatly that didn't work, the result was:

I don't have the folder named `dist` so I created it and the json ouputed was the following:

```json
{"version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", "hash": ""}
```

did I do something wrong ?

**EDIT 2 / RESOLVE**

I searched why there is no 'hash' in the json generated and found that my **webpack.config.js** was

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    filename: '[hash].bundle.js',
  },
};
```

instead of

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    filename: '[contenthash].bundle.js',
  },
};
```

changed that resolved my problem.

Thanks to @GaëlMarziou comment that put me on the way.

Comment: Have you read this article? https://medium.com/@aakashbumiya/auto-reload-for-clients-after-deploy-with-angular-7-production-build-bdc45be9b2bd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CF: EDIT 2
Thanks again to Mr. Marziou